# I have tried a proof $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}x^2=1\,.\,$ I know it is wrong but could you tell me where?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I have tried a proof $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}x^2=1\,.\,$ I know it is wrong but could you tell me where ?

By $\,\delta\,,\,\varepsilon\,$ definition $\;|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon\,$, $\;|x-0|<\delta$

1. $-\varepsilon<x^2-1<\varepsilon$
2. $-\varepsilon+1<x^2<\varepsilon+1$
3. $\sqrt{(-\varepsilon+1)}<x<\sqrt{(\varepsilon+1)}$

So I take $\,\delta\,$ as $\,\sqrt{(1 - \varepsilon)}\,.$

Comment: Here is a quick introduction on how to use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), in order to properly type Maths expressions

Comment: @DominikS thank you!

Comment: Your steps are for making x tend to 1. [as e goes to 0 your line 3 is forcing x to go to 1.] However in your problem you are investigating the limit as x tends to 0.

Comment: @coffeemath No i want it to be to 0 only

Comment: I mean your steps make it go to 1. So you need other steps.

Comment: so, you mean everytime I solve a question on limits using the delta epsilon then I have to check the inequalities at the limit point??

Comment: @nithyamanish, the step 1. is wrong, in fact since $\,|x|<\delta\,$ the first inequality of the step 1. is not right for $\,0<\varepsilon\leqslant1-\delta^2\,.\;$

Comment: okay, now i get it. so I should check the inequalities before continuing

Comment: @nithyamanish, yes, you should check the inequalities before continuing, in fact the first inequality of the step 1. is not right for $\,0<\varepsilon\leqslant1-\delta^2\,.\;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your step 3,

> 3. $\sqrt{1-\epsilon} < x < \sqrt{1+\epsilon}$

This is a region roughly centered around $x=1$. In particular, when $\epsilon$ is very small, you cannot put e.g. $x=0.001$ to satisfy the inequality. When $\epsilon<1$, $x=0$ doesn't belong to the set.

The set $|x|<\delta$ is a small region around $0$. If you put $\delta = \sqrt{1-\epsilon}$ then that means you are considering $|x|<\sqrt{1-\epsilon}$ i.e. $$-\sqrt{1-\epsilon} < x < \sqrt{1-\epsilon}.$$ In fact these two regions are completely disjoint.

Hope [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yqyqt9deyl) sends the point home:
[image]

Comment: Thank you sir, I get it and it means that I should take check the inequalities before proceding

Comment: Calvin, also the step 1. is wrong indeed also $\,-\varepsilon<x^2-1<\varepsilon\,$ represents a region roughly centered around $\,x=1\,.\;$

Comment: @Angelo yes well whether or not that is wrong is more open to debate. One strategy for proving a limit is to start from what you want and work backwards to find $\delta$: So here, I understood OP as starting from the desired conclusion ("$|x^2-1|<\epsilon$"). I don't know if it is strictly wrong to manipulate this expression until line 3, but it is definitely wrong to say that you can pick $\delta=\sqrt{1-\epsilon}$ so that is what I tried to point out

Answer (score 0):

We need to assume that $\epsilon<1$, and this is without loss of generality.

Next you have that:

4. $\sqrt{(-\epsilon + 1)}-1 < x-1 < \sqrt{(\epsilon + 1)}-1$

Take $\delta=\min\{\sqrt{(\epsilon + 1)}-1,1-\sqrt{(-\epsilon + 1)}\}$.

In fact  setting
$$
1-\sqrt{(-\epsilon + 1)}
=\frac{\epsilon}{1+\sqrt{(1-\epsilon)}}>\frac{\epsilon}{3},
$$
we obtain
$$
|x-1|<\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3}\Longrightarrow
|x^2-1|=|x-1||x+1|\le |x-1| (|x-1|+2)\le \delta (2+\delta)< 3\delta =\epsilon.
$$

Comment: I don't get it, I have followed in the same way that $ |f(x)-L|<\epsilon $ and $ |x-0|<\delta $